# Is it possible to remove duplicates from a List containing elements of a custom type?

Tags: java

This is my code

```
package com.dto;

public class OtherBrands {

    private String otherbrandsname ;
    public String getOtherbrandsname() {
        return otherbrandsname;
    }
    public void setOtherbrandsname(String otherbrandsname) {
        this.otherbrandsname = otherbrandsname;
    }
    public String getDealerBrandQty() {
        return dealerBrandQty;
    }
    public void setDealerBrandQty(String dealerBrandQty) {
        this.dealerBrandQty = dealerBrandQty;
    }
    private String dealerBrandQty ;

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.dto.OtherBrands;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List < OtherBrands > otherBrandsList = new ArrayList < OtherBrands > ();
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            OtherBrands otherbrands = new OtherBrands();
            String otherbrandsname = "Test";
            String dealerBrandQty = "2";
            otherbrands.setOtherbrandsname(otherbrandsname);
            otherbrands.setDealerBrandQty(dealerBrandQty);
            otherBrandsList.add(otherbrands);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<otherBrandsList.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(otherBrandsList.get(i).getOtherbrandsname()+"\t"+otherBrandsList.get(i).getDealerBrandQty());

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program,  the result is :

```
Test    2
Test    2
Test    2
```

**If the key and value are the same, it should be treated as duplicate**

Is it possible to remove the duplicates from the list?

Comment: You can use `set` instead and in your dto do remember to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.

Comment: Have you tried with `Map` type?

Comment: while adding elements to `list` you can check whether new element is already exists or not. this you can do by override  `hashCode()` and `equals()` method. this can be done by `HashSet` also, there also you need to override both methods. read contract rules of these method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you want to avoid duplicates, use a HashSet instead of a List.

Second of all, you have to override `hashCode` and `equals` in order for the `HashSet` to know which elements you consider to be equal to each other.

```
public class OtherBrands {

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        if (!(other instanceof OtherBrands))
            return false;
        OtherBrands ob = (OtherBrands) other;
        // add some checks here to handle any of the properties being null
        return otherbrandsname.equals(ob.otherbrandsname) &&
               dealerBrandQty.equals(ob.dealerBrandQty);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode(new String[]{dealerBrandQty,otherbrandsname});
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use Hashset , as same name can appear twice with diferent quantity .

Comment: define your equals method based on `name` and `quantity`. You have some criteria right based on which you are saying duplicate. Implement your equals method in the same way.

Comment: @PreethiJain You can use HashSet if you define that two objects are equal if they have the same name and the same quantity

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList`, because it guarantees removal of duplicate items. It only requires you to implement the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in the `OtherBrands` class.

As a tip, if you use Eclipse: you can generate both methods with the editor menu feature ' Source/Generate HashCode and Equals '. Then select all the attributes, that define the identity of an `OtherBrands` item (name, quantity).

Comment: can i still use hashset ??  
 as same name can appear twice with diferent quantity .

Comment: Yes you can, but this depends on the implementation of hashCode() and equals(), as these methods determine identity for the HashSet.